# Dart: consistently replace last n digits in an alphanumeric string

Tags: regex, string, dart, replace

I need to de-identify strings of predominately (but not exclusively) digits, in a way that is *consistent and deterministic regardless of the non-digit formatting of the string*. I do not want to replace ALL of the digits of a string, just the last ~60-80% of digits.

Long numbers like phone numbers show this, basically I need:

```
"01234567890123" => "01230000000000"
"+ (012) 34-567-890-123" => "+ (012) 30-000-000-000"
```

The first code I used was a simple combo of regex and `substring`, but split the non-replaced/replaced sections of the string by total string length, so the split-point was inconsistent if there was formatting:

```
String deidentString = original.substring(0, original.length ~/ 2.5) +
  original.substring(original.length ~/ 2.5).replaceAll(RegExp('[0-9]'), '0');
```

This does not return consistent numbers in the de-identified string when original numbers are formatted differently, particularly when strings get longer and non-digit characters appear unevenly throughout the string.

Thus the above code gives:

```
"01234567890123" => "01234000000000"
"+ (012) 34-567-890-123" => "+ (012) 00-000-000-000"
```

So far I HAVE managed to solve this with a very inelegant mix of looping and conditionals:

```
void main() {
  List l = ['01234567890123', '+ (012) 34-567-890-123'];
  l.forEach((s) {
    int replaceFrom = s.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\D'),'').length ~/ 2.5;
    int replaceChar = 0;
    int intCount = 0;
    s.split('').asMap().forEach((i,char) {
      if ((s.codeUnitAt(i) ^ 0x30) <= 9) {
        intCount += 1;
        if (intCount == replaceFrom) {replaceChar = i;}
      }
    });
    print("$s => ${s.substring(0,replaceChar)}${s.substring(replaceChar).replaceAll(RegExp(r'\d'),'0')}");
  });
}
```

There must be a better way? I did try RegEx with non-capturing groups, but these were poorly supported in Dart.

*(Note: the exact point of where the string is de-identified is not critical, just that a string of digits should be de-identified to the SAME digits regardless of non-digit formatting.)*

Comment: This is quite unrealistic to be solved with regexes if you don't know any specific format. Regexes should be used when you have clear and not too complex rules to parse the string. If you can have strings like `012345678901 23` and `01234-567-890-123` and `3004.4004` it's not really possible to get last 60%. You could use multiple regexes, one per each possible format, but an algorithmic solution is just way easier.

Comment: And your algorithm is more or less fine, although some other bit different variants come to mind, hard to judge what would be the fastest though without knowing how many strings have non-digits, etc.

Comment: Thanks Destroy / good points. Agree there's a tension here between a generalised solution and wide variety of string formats that could be thrown at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything you do here, get it verified by your local privacy or legal council.
Anonymization is *hard*. Possibly impossible in general.
(For example, retaining the area code of a phone number is still exposing very useful information about where in the country an entry comes from. And not all identifying digit sequences have the most specific digits at the end.)

Anyway, if we assume that you actually can use what you are asking for,
let's be precise about what you consider a successful implementation:

- An input consisting of any number of digits and non-digits.
- At least 60% of digits will be replaced by '0'.
- Must be the *last* 60% of digit.
- Should be efficient?

The brute-force approach would:

- Find all digits: `var digits = RegExp(r"\d").allMatches(input).toList();`.
- Count them: `var digitCount = digits.length;`
- Replace the last 60% with `"0"`:

  ```dart
  for (var m in digits.skip(digitCount * 4 ~/ 10)) { // Skip first 40% 
    input = input.replaceRange(m.start, m.end, "0");
  }
  ```

If that's an acceptable behavior, then all that's left to worry about is being efficient.
I assume this will be used against a large number of inputs, since anonymization only really makes sense when the population is large enough
to hide in. So efficiency matters.

Repeated replacements is not efficient in long strings, but in short strings, it's *possibly* not as bad. Still causes as lot of allocations and can cause garbage-collection churn.

We can make a number of assumptions then:

- Every input will have digits. (If not, detecting the ones without and doing nothing for them is cheaper, if they all have digits, we can skip that check.)
- Every input will have a significant proportion of digits. (If some have only a few digits, spending too much time on non-digits can be wasteful, and a `String.replaceAll` may be more efficient, if every string had >80% digits, copying everything to a `Uint8List` buffer and working directly on that might be more efficient.)
- Every input is ASCII, or at least Latin-1. If not, the buffer will a have to be a `Uint16List`.)

Let's assume the first two. The third one is reasonably to handle.

```dart
import "dart:typed_data";
String anonymize(String input) {
  var digitCount = 0;
  var bits = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    var c = input.codeUnitAt(i);
    bits |= c;
    if (c ^ 0x30 <= 9) digitCount++;
  }
  // if (digitCount == 0) return input;
  List<int> chars = bits <= 255
      ? Uint8List.fromList(input.codeUnits) 
      : Uint16List.fromList(input.codeUnits);
  var skip = digitCount * 4 ~/ 10;
  for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    if (chars[i] ^ 0x30 <= 9) { 
      if (skip <= 0) {
        chars[i] = 0x30; // '0'
      } else {
        skip--;
      }
    }
  }
  return String.fromCharCodes(chars);
}
```

If you can accept any number between 60% and 80%, it might be possible
to approximate the cut-off point a little cheaper than doing two iterations.

Comment: Thanks @lrn. Very comprehensive answer / esp. considering privacy challenges. The efficiency of your second algorithm exceeds what I thought was possible!